# SPI communication with Arduino and PGA411-Q1 resolver sensor

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, c, spi

I have been trying to implement SPI communication between an Arduino board and a PGA411-Q1 resolver sensor board. I have set up the Arduino SPI settings as indicated on the resolver sensor's datasheet (http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa688/slaa688.pdf) - 8MHz sclock, MSB first and SPIMode1.

The communication is done by sending and receiving 32 bits both to and from the Arduino. The bits are distributed as follows.

Outgoing 32bit data frame by Arduino to the sensor:

O-5 bits: Arduino's CRC for data 
6-7 bits: Always zero 
8-23 bits: Data 
24-31 bits: Register address

Incoming 32bit data frame by the sensor to the Arduino:

O-5 bits: Sensor's CRC for data 
6-7 bits: SPI communication status 
8-23 bits: Data 
24-31 bits: Register address

Also, there is mandatory to send and receive a CRC6 code from both the board and Arduino and I have implemented it as well. (I will not be checking the CRC code received by the Arduino board. I will check it later. But I am already sending the CRC code needed by the sensor board).

This is the code written by me:

NOTE: The crc_cal function outputs the crc code from Arduino to the sensor along with the two 'always zero' bits.

```
#include <SPI.h>
unsigned int crc_cal (unsigned long datin);


 const int ncs = 10;
 unsigned char crc_char = 0x3F;



 void setup() {

  // initalize the chip select pin:
  pinMode(ncs, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(FAULTRES,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(NRESET,OUTPUT);

  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //NRESET must go from LOW to HIGH 
  digitalWrite(NRESET,LOW);
  digitalWrite(NRESET,HIGH);

  //wait at least 5ms to complete diagnostics tests
  delay(10);

  //FAULTRES LOW
  digitalWrite(FAULTRES,LOW);

  // start the SPI library:
  SPI.begin();


 // give the sensor time to set up:
  delay(100);


   }






void loop() {

SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(6400000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE1));

digitalWrite(ncs, LOW);

byte temp_3 = SPI.transfer(0x41);

byte temp_2 = SPI.transfer(0x0F);

byte temp_1 = SPI.transfer(0x0F);

byte temp_0 = SPI.transfer(crc_char);

digitalWrite(ncs, HIGH);

SPI.endTransaction();  


unsigned int angle_raw = 0;
angle_raw = temp_2;
angle_raw = angle_raw << 8;
angle_raw = angle_raw | temp_1;
angle_raw &= 0x3FF; 
Serial.println(angle_raw);




int crc = crc_cal(0x410F0F00);
unsigned char crc_char = crc;
crc_char = crc_char & 0x3F;
 delay(100);


 }

     /* CRC6 calculation - optimized for PGA411 */
 unsigned int crc_cal (unsigned long datin)
 {
 unsigned int byte_idx, bit_idx, crc= (0x3F << 2);
 /* byte by byte starting from most significant (3-2-1) */
 for (byte_idx = 3; byte_idx >= 1; byte_idx--)
 {
 /* XOR-in new byte from left to right */
 crc ^= ((datin >> (byte_idx<<3)) & 0x000000FF);
 /* bit by bit for each byte */
 for(bit_idx = 0; bit_idx < 8; bit_idx++)
 {
 crc = crc << 1 ^ (crc & 0x80 ? (0x5B << 2) : 0);
 }
 }
 return(crc >> 2 & 0x3F); /*restore two bit offset */


 }
```

I have used the code provided in the PGA411-Q1's datasheet (http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa688/slaa688.pdf) and it works fine when I check it manually. Some examples for input data frames and their CRC codes can be found in the section 7.5.4 of the datasheet found here http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pga411-q1.pdf

As you may notice from the code I am sending the register address which I want data from in the first 8 bits of SPI.transfer. The read address of that register is 0x41.

Next, I'm sending two garbage values as data because this is a read-only register.

Finally, I'm sending the CRC code calculated by the crc_cal function.

All I'm receiving in the serial monitor are zeros and I can't figure out what went wrong. I would appreciate some insight into this.

Comment: Why are you sending a CRC value calculated from values that you received? In my understanding you send a CRC value calculated from the values, that you are sending

Comment: @chrisl I have fixed it now. Still no change.

Comment: Then please update your question with your new code. In the linked application note I see an initialization process. But I don't find point 2 and point 5 in your program: "Step 2.  Ensure that the NRESET signal has a low-to-high transition. Step 5.  Set the FAULTRES pin logic low." May be a good thing to include that also

Comment: hello @chrisl the FAULTRES pin can be set to zero by the GUI software that comes with the sensor board. I have already set it low. Also, the NRESET can be made low-to-high by manually pressing the pin associated with the NRESET pin. I have done both but still no progress.

Comment: I have separately connected NRESET and FAULTRES pins to pin 4 and 3 of Arduino board and have updated the code